# Trying to send email in Java using gmail always results in username and password not accepted

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

When I call the send method (after setting studentAddress), I get this:

`javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

535 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 y15sm906936wfd.10`

I'm pretty sure the code is correct, and 100% positive that the username and password details I'm entering are correct. So is this something wrong with gmail or what?

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail {

    private String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String emailLogin = "xxx@gmail.com";
    private String pass = "xxx";
    private String studentAddress;
    private String to;
    private Properties props = System.getProperties();

    public SendEmail() {
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", emailLogin);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        to = "xxx@gmail.com";
    }

    public void setStudentAddress(String newAddress) {
        studentAddress = newAddress;
    }

    public void send() {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailLogin));

            InternetAddress[] studentAddressList = {new InternetAddress(studentAddress)};
            message.setReplyTo(studentAddressList);
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Test Email");
            message.setText("This is a test email!");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
            transport.connect(host, emailLogin, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            System.out.println("There has been an email error!");
            me.printStackTrace();           
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas...

Comment: To narrow something down, if you change to .getTransport("smtp") does it work?

Comment: Actually I just figured it out, the code is fine. I used a different gmail account to the one I was testing with and it worked perfectly. So for some reason the gmail account that I just set up an hour ago to test this code with isn't working properly? I have enabled pop in its settings so I'm unsure why this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

There are two solution for this:

You can generate the application specific password by the link i.e "https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens" and 
**use the generated application specific password in place your original password**
. I have done this and its working

or

The reason why the Exception (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.1 Application-specific password required) is occurring is that you may have activated the 2-step verification of your gmail account. If you use an account in which you do not activate the 2-step verification then you can send the email by you original password. I have also tried this and its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue exactly (using commons-email which indeed seems easier than using java.mail).
What solved it for me was changing the user name to include the user@mydomain.com instead of just "user".
Probably a new-b mistake but perhaps others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Was an issue to do with gmail, not the code!

Answer (score 0):

there are certain restrictions for a gmail account to be used in a program as yours. One among that is the account should be some days old and i guess its 1 days old.